# Redirect to undefined after login to back office in prestashop

Tags: redirect, admin, prestashop

I have a problem with prestashop (version: 1.4.4.1) after some problems with domains and database, all configurations connected with them were changed to correct ones (PS_SHOP_DOMAIN and PS_SHOP_DOMAIN_SSL in ps_configuration table are set correctly and the cache and compile folders were cleared and of course database config in settings.inc.php) and the Front Office works fine but after login to Back Office the Back Office's page shows for a second and after that the page is redirect to 404 page - I've noticed that address to which the redirect is set is: admindir/undefined and also I found the source of this redirect: redirect function in js/ajax.js (line 131) (but the real source unfortunately is unknown). Strange thing is that when I moved the system to localhost it works fine.

What do you think, what is the problem?

Comment: At first, try to remove cookies, cache and all that stuff, sounds silly, however when there is a great headache, in most cases it helps :-). Secondly, if you disable JS, do you get 404?

Comment: "if you disable JS, do you get 404" I didn't realy disable JS - I only changed one function in js file (redirect in ajax.js) and after that the redirects stoped and this error currently disapear but probably it is not the best solution.